# How can I make this, combineAndSortLists([tasks, tasklists], "order"), a typesafe generic function

Tags: arrays, typescript, sorting, typescript-generics

```
export function combineAndSortLists<T>(lists: T[][], sortKey: keyof T):T[] {
   const combinedList = [];

   for (let i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
      const list = lists[i];
      for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
         const item = list[j];
         combinedList.push(item);
      }
   }
   combinedList.sort((a, b) => (a[sortKey] ?? 0) - (b[sortKey] ?? 0));
   return combinedList
}
```

This is my current attempt but `combineAndSortLists([tasks, taskslists], "order")` throws errors returns `const combineAndSortLists: <Task>(lists: Task[][], sortKey: keyof Task) => Task[]`

What I want is for the function to return `Array<Task | Tasklist>`. Then again, is this how I should be solving this problem of combining different arrays and sorting via a common key?

Minimal Reproducible Example

```
export function combineAndSortLists<T>(lists: T[][], sortKey: keyof T): T[] {
  const combinedList = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    const list = lists[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
      const item = list[j];
      combinedList.push(item);
    }
  }
  combinedList.sort((a, b) => (a[sortKey] ?? 0) - (b[sortKey] ?? 0));
  return combinedList;
}

interface Task {
  id?: number;
  task: string;
  done: boolean;
  tasklistId?: number | null;
  group?: "tasks" | "tasksDone";
  order?: number;
}

interface Tasklist {
  id?: number;
  title: string;
  tasks: Task[];
  done?: boolean;
  group?: "tasks" | "tasksDone";
  order?: number;
}

const tasks: Task[] = [{ task: "Wake up", done: false, order: 0 }];
const tasklists: Tasklist[] = [{ title: "Morning Tasks", tasks: [{ task: "Eat", done: true}, { task: "Work out", done: false }], order: 1 }];
const newlist = combineAndSortLists<Task | Tasklist>([tasks, tasklists], "order");
console.log(newlist);
```

Can I do this without providing type while using the function because the function should work with an arbitrary number of lists? Also I how I fix the subtraction error in `combinedList.sort()`: `The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.`?

The responses so far have sooo helpful and I have learnt so much.

Comment: Can you include some test cases where you use the function so that we have a reference

Comment: Just did. How is it?

Comment: Can you also include types for `Task` and `Tasklist`?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that others can paste into their own IDEs to see what you're seeing. Right now you haven't defined `Task` or `Tasklist` or described the error in detail; I can guess what they look like and that will show me the error, but that should really be in the question itself directly.  Also I think you have unrelated errors you want to clear up inside the function body (subtracting things which might not be numbers), and you should remove them if you can to prevent distractions.

Comment: (see prev comment) Assuming I've guessed correctly, the issue is that TS doesn't like to synthesize union types for type arguments; you could refactor to something like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WP8bZW).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am  I missing?

Comment: Your solution works so well on the playground but this is what I get in my Code (VsCode) `Type 'Task[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly Record<"order", number>[]'.`

Comment: You've already accepted another answer so I'm not inclined to engage further. If you need something else let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible typescript infer unions types automatically, do you need manually inform this with "<type1 | type2>", so your code will seems like

```
type Task = {task: string, order?: number};
type TaskList = {tasks: Task[], order?: number};

export function combineAndSortLists<T>(lists: T[][], sortKey: keyof T): T[] {
   const combinedList = [];

   for (let i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
      const list = lists[i];
      for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
         const item = list[j];
         combinedList.push(item);
      }
   }
   combinedList.sort((a, b) => {
      const normalizedA = a[sortKey] ?? 0;
      const normalizedB = b[sortKey] ?? 0;
      if ( normalizedA < normalizedB )return -1;
      if ( normalizedA > normalizedB ) return 1;
      return 0;
   });
   return combinedList;
}

const tasks: Task[] = [{task: "Wake up", order: 0}];
const tasklists: TaskList[] = [{tasks:[{task: "East"}, {task: "Work out"}], order: 1}];
const newlist = combineAndSortLists<Task | TaskList>([tasks, tasklists], "order");
console.log(newlist);
```

Comment: This was very helpful. How do I fix the TS err in `combinedList.sort(): The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.`?

Comment: I get this error `Type 'Task[]' is not assignable to type '(Task[] | Tasklist[])[]'` at `combineAndSortLists<Task | TaskList>([tasks, tasklists], "order");` Same with Tasklist

Comment: i uptated the anwser to resolve this typescript erros